# to_string vs cast to string, and operator<<

Tags: string, c++11, casting, conventions

I am wondering what the best way to implement conversion to string is for my own classes. I have searched extensively (and consulted some books), but surprisingly I have not found any recommendations anywhere. As I see it, the options are:

Inside-class definition of the cast to string:
`operator std::string() const`

Outside-class overloading of
`std::string to_string(const Obj&)`

Related to this: is it beter to declare the overload of the streaming operator `<<` inside the class or outside?

Comment: Using a stand-alone (non-member) function [is in the standard for numeric types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string), but if it's "better" is up for debate.

Comment: As for where possible output (or input) operators should be declared, that depends very much on if they need to be friends with the class. If they need to be friends then you *must* declare them in the class. Also note that if you declare a function in a class without the `friend` specifier, then it's declares as a member function, which is most likely not what you want for an output operator, if you're supposed to pass the object to a stream.

Comment: What I didn't write in my original post is that I lean towards to_string, since this then conforms with those for the standard numeric types.

So then if the string conversion / streaming doesn't require `friend`ship, it's best to declare them outside the class?

Answer (score 3):

I'd say it depends on the type of string you're trying to generate. If it's for logging and debugging, I'd probably overload `<<(ostream&)`, provided my logging library supports streams (or can be mode to support it).

If it makes sense as a string without surprising anyone (the upcoming `string_view` being one example), then I'd do the operator. If it's a number type (like a big integer), or any other type that for any other reason needs to have a string representation, I'd add a `ToString()` function, whether member or not.

I *wouldn't*, however, add a `std::to_string()` overload, since I wouldn't want to sneak into the `std` namespace with my own non-standard code. Also, you can't even use it ADL contexts, since `std::to_string()` only takes primitive operands.

As for the `<<(ostream&)` operator, there's no use declaring it as a member function, since `os << myObj` wouldn't work. What you *can* do is declare it as a friend and then have its definition inside the class declaration. This, however, would make it a non-member function, because of the `friend` keyword. The safest bet is, usually, to declare it as a friend and the provide the implementation in a source file.

Comment: `<<` doesn't convert to string. My question concerns conversion to string. (For the streamer, I usually then call to_string or the cast, with some further adornment if necessary.)

Comment: @DanielGr Sorry, I was implying the use of `std::ostringstream` for such a conversion, which is quite idiomatic.